How do I get Client.User and Clients.Users with authenticated and authorized user in Azure SignalR hub
Following the guidance provided by Michael Washington at learn.microsoft.com we have finally gotten the Context.User.Identity to populate with our authenticated user and the correct NameIdentifier value in Context.User.Identity.Name for our chat hub with Azure SignalR. We are using Cookies to authenticate a user that has logged into our IdentityServer. In the OnConnectedAsync override we can see that Context.User.Identity is correct; and we've added the [Authorize] to our hub. However, when sending a hub message either through the hub or using a HubContext the Clients.User and Clients.Users are null so we cannot send messages directly to users. Is this a known issue? We are using Azure.SignalR v. 1.25.2 and AspnetCore.SignalR.Client.Core v 8.04.
We have followed the Azure SignalR documentation and examples, have set cookie container in WithUrl method. We can see that we have an authenticate/authorized user, but are unable to send messages directly to the user with Clients.User(userId).SendAsync since Clients.User is null.

How can Clients.User be null? It's a method.

How would you refer to a method that is there in code but not there at runtime?

That would result in a MissingMethodException if that's what you're hitting.
